How to find your contract and employee handbook in the UK?
When talking to employment lawyer friends about workplace issues, they always suggest you read your employment contract and the employee handbook. But as far as I can tell these things don't exist at the universities I have worked at, at least for academics.
There are university web pages that generally discuss policy for all staff (academic and non academic) and include lines like "All staff should have a job description for their post which will be provided on joining the University".  Maybe this counts as an employee handbook. But I have no idea how to get hold of my contract.
Has anyone worked out how to get a copy of their employment contract at a UK university?

Try searching for the word "contract" in whatever email address you were using to communicate with the university before you were hired.

@deee that is too long ago now sadly.

The official letter that offered you employment, together with your job description and the university general terms and conditions of employment (which apply to all staff) jointly constitute your contract. At both universities I have worked at,  the terms and conditions have been linked in the offer letter.  You might also find them by searching your intranet for terms and conditions.

To add a bit more detail, all of mine start with the words "I am please to formally offer an appointment as Position X in University Y". The last bit in all of them is "I am pleased to accept the offer of appointment as set out in this letter and in the enclosed statement of main terms and conditions" (and then has a line for a singature and date). I found that the older of my documents are scans which have my physical signature (with a pen) scanned it. The latest one I have is not signed; I suspect that's because post-covid, they decided that "an approval through e-mail" is just as valid.

And then I also have a document (which I received with my offer letter; but that was the current version at the time and it is possible that it changed) titled "University of X Statement of Main Terms and Conditions of Employment For Academic Higher Education Staff, Grade 7 – 10". I'm guessing that's the "employee handbook" to which the OP was referring

@penelope We have a "Summary of terms and conditions" and a (much longer) "Full Terms and Conditions". The Full Terms and conditions makes reference to the "HR Policy Website".

You should have signed a contract before you started working. As Ian writes, it may not have said "contract" but "offer letter", but either way, it spelled out the terms of your employment, your duties, your remuneration and other perks, and if applicable, the length of your employment. You should have gotten that in duplicate, one to return signed, one to keep. This is your contract, and yes, you should keep this in a secure location. (If you are paranoid like me, you scan it and keep the PDF on external hard drives in three separate places.)
Your employee handbook is typically somewhere on the intranet, or you can ask HR about it. The fun part here is that this can and will change, without this being announced. If you take some action based on your understanding of the handbook, it is always good to check first whether your understanding was correct. I have seen perks disappear silently: one year, everyone would get reimbursed for a public transport half fare card, one year later it would only be "with manager approval". And yes, such unilateral changes are usually quite legal. (If you are even more paranoid than me, you keep time-stamped local copies to show that what you did at point in time X was in accordance with the handbook at that time.)
Overall, this is really more a question for Workplace.SE.

If you have been at an organization for a non-trivial time, you may have accumulated letters of modification to your contract (most commonly in the form of any changes to your pay), such that the actual state of your contract may not be in a single document.

Per the comments, it seems like you no longer have your copy of the contract that was agreed to when you started. You may have some luck requesting a copy of your contract from HR as they will certainly have a copy.
The "employee handbook" is likely to be a collection of pages on your intranet which may or may not be coherent or easily accessible.
If you have problems getting your contract from HR, your union branch will probably be able to help. CC'ing your union rep on an email to HR often helps with issues like this. Similarly, if you have a question about a workplace issue then your union may be able to answer, as the reps are likely to be fairly familiar with relevant employment law, university policies, and the arcane machinations of university administration. If you don't have a local branch then the place to contact is your regional office.
(If you're not a member of your union branch, consider joining - it's not very much money and gives you access to a support when you're having the kind of issues that mean you're looking for your contract. In the UK it's generally UCU or Unison - academic staff have to join UCU and professional services staff can join either.)
